# `XCTest` for a custom `XCTestCase` assert

Tags: swift, unit-testing, concurrency, xctest

Apple *Concurrency* framework is lacking support for async version of `XCTAssertThrowsError`. I have created a public function as a substitute for it.

```swift
func XCTAssertThrowsErrorAsync<T>(_ expression: @autoclosure () async throws -> T,
                                  _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
                                  _ handler: (_ error: Error) -> Void = { _ in },
                                  file: StaticString = #filePath,
                                  line: UInt = #line) async {
    do {
        _ = try await expression() as T

        XCTFail(
            message(),
            file: file,
            line: line
        )
    } catch {
        handler(error)
    }
}
```

I would like to cover this function with unit tests.

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If this is internal to your project: I extract custom test assertions from existing test cases. Then I manually break code to confirm that the assertion works the way I want it to. I especially want to see if I can make failure messages more informative.

I do this manually, without automation.

But if you intend to publish this to open source, then it makes sense to get test coverage. The goal would be to give developers who are not working with you immediate feedback on changes they make to your test framework.

I assume you know how to test the `handler(error)` call. (If you don't, let me know so I can add to this answer.) The problem is, how do we test the call to `XCTFail`? Here's how we did it to write ApprovalTests.Swift:

```swift
import XCTest

public protocol Failer {
    func fail(_ message: String, file: StaticString, line: UInt) throws
}

public struct XCTFailer: Failer {
    public func fail(_ message: String, file: StaticString, line: UInt) throws {
        XCTFail(message, file: file, line: line)
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Swift/blob/master/ApprovalTests.Swift/Approvers/TestFailer.swift

Instead of calling `XCTFail` directly, we introduced a `Failer` protocol. By default, our code uses an `XCTFailer()` which calls the `XCTFail` for real. To test it, inject a Test Spy instead.